Interpolating ListDensityPlot of integer valued data
I have a set of data of the type {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...} where z1 is either 1, 2 or 3.
When I plot it using a ListDensityPlot[], I obtain the following:
Show[ListDensityPlot[DataClean, ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\[Gamma]", "V"}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  PlotLabel -> "Number of  non-negative solutions", 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRange -> {{0.005, 2/\[Pi]}, {0, 1}}], 
 Plot[Sqrt[\[Gamma] (2/\[Pi] - \[Gamma])], {\[Gamma], 0, 2/\[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.01]}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]]


Since I want only integer values in the plot, I set the interpolation order to 0. Is there an easy way to interpolate the data such that the lines separating the 3 regions of the plot are smoothed out?
